# Given a valley_list. Find the integer key in the given valley list in python

Tags: python-3.x

Input:
first-line will contain the valley_list and the second line will contain the element key to be found in the list. No repetition of elements in the valley_list.

Output:
index of the element key in the valley_list if it is present else -1.

Sample input:
list = [13, 11, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1, 14, 15, 16, 17]
key to find = 8

Sample output:
2

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if key not in valley_list:
    output = -1
else:
    output = valley_list.index(key)
```

Comment: thanks for responding ...this code is working..but i have asked to use binary search to solve this problem